# Transaction complete, but NFT not transferred

Tags: ethereum, nft, openzeppelin

I created a smart contract, minted an nft, and now trying to transfer it.
My problem is that transaction completes fine- I can see it in etherscan etc, but nft is not transferred. What are the possible root causes?

```
async function transferNFT() {
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(PUBLIC_KEY, 'latest'); //get latest nonce

  //the transaction
    const tx = {
      'from': sender,
      'to': receiver,
      'nonce': nonce,
      'gas': 500000,
      'data': myContract.methods.transferFrom(sender,receiver, 1).encodeABI()
    }

    const signPromise = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY)
    signPromise
    .then((signedTx) => {
        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
        signedTx.rawTransaction,
        function (err, hash) {
            if (!err) {
            console.log(
                "The hash of your transaction is: ",
                hash,
                "\nCheck Alchemy's Mempool to view the status of your transaction!"
            )
            } else {
            console.log(
                "Something went wrong when submitting your transaction:",
                err
            )
            }
        }
        )
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(" Promise failed:", err)
    })

}
transferNFT()
```

And the contract. I actually don't call the transfer function as I was expecting to use the openzeppelin transferFrom function. But if I use the transfer function from the contract - the result is the same:

- transaction is executed
- NFT is not transferred.

  ```
   contract MyNFTv2 is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
       using Counters for Counters.Counter;
       Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
       event NftBought(address _seller, address _buyer, uint256 _price);
       event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 indexed _tokenId);

   mapping (uint256 => uint256) public tokenIdToPrice;
   mapping(uint256 => address) internal idToOwner;


   constructor() public ERC721("MyNFTv2", "NFT") {}

   function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI)
       public onlyOwner
       returns (uint256)
   {
       _tokenIds.increment();

       uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
       _mint(recipient, newItemId);
       _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

       return newItemId;
   }

   function allowBuy(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _price) external {
       require(msg.sender == ownerOf(_tokenId), 'Not owner of this token');
       require(_price > 0, 'Price zero');
       tokenIdToPrice[_tokenId] = _price;
   }

   function disallowBuy(uint256 _tokenId) external {
       require(msg.sender == ownerOf(_tokenId), 'Not owner of this token');
       tokenIdToPrice[_tokenId] = 0;
   }

   function buy(uint256 _tokenId) external payable {
       uint256 price = tokenIdToPrice[_tokenId];
       require(price > 0, 'This token is not for sale');
       require(msg.value == price, 'Incorrect value');

       address seller = ownerOf(_tokenId);
       _transfer(seller, msg.sender, _tokenId);
       tokenIdToPrice[_tokenId] = 0; // not for sale anymore
       payable(seller).transfer(msg.value); // send the ETH to the seller

       emit NftBought(seller, msg.sender, msg.value);
   }

   function transfer(address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public {
       require(msg.sender == idToOwner[_tokenId]);
       idToOwner[_tokenId] = _to;
       emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _tokenId);
   }
  ```

  }

Comment: It depends on the `transferFrom()` contract function. Can you share it, including its dependencies (or link to the full contract source code)?

Comment: I have shared the contract code. But I thought it will use the default openzeppeline transferFrom function?

Comment: Ok I wasn't aware that you're using the OpenZeppelin (and not custom) implementation. Does it fail with a specific error message? Or just the generic `has been reverted`?  Can you link one of the failed transfers on a blockchain explorer?

Comment: Its on ropsten testnet: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xb677a1f1bb2d01ba8766a24cb593eb2b26131a72cf46bd926ded6fae77021d7a
It says transaction successful, but NFT transfer doesn't happen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const tx = {
    'from': sender,
    'to': receiver,
```

You're sending the transaction to the token receiver, which is a regular address that doesn't hold any smart contract.

So when you pass them the `data` field, there's no contract to process it and the transaction just passes through ignoring the `data` field.

**Solution:** Set the `to` field of the transaction to the NFT collection contract. Then it will be able to process the `tranferFrom()` function and its arguments passed in the `data` field. Note that the `receiver` is already passed in the 2nd argument of the function.